# Using Azure File Copy Task in Azure DevOps to Copy Data from Storage Account to Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azcopy

I have the following YAML configured but guessing I cannot use a storage account for a source input here?  I assumed I could since the task simply uses azcopy (note: the command works fine from command line just not in the pipeline (i.e. permissions are set (e.g. SPN has been authorized and RBAC set).

Here's the code:

```
trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
steps:
 #Copy files to Azure Blob Storage
- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  inputs:
    sourcePath: 'https://someonesbackups.blob.core.windows.net/backups?mysastokengoeshere'
    azureSubscription: MY-Production-Subscription
    destination: azureBlob
    storage: azcopypipelinetest
    containerName: restored
    additionalArgumentsForBlobCopy: --recursive=true
```

However, when that runs I get the following error:

```
"failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot scan the path \\?\D:\a\1\s\https:\someonesbackups.blob.core.windows.net\backups?mysastokengoeshere=-REDACTED-, please verify that it is a valid."
```

Certainly seems as though you could do this but guessing I'm missing something fundamental here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops

Comment: So, this one is a head-scratcher, to be sure - I've looked at the Powershell for the `AzureFileCopy@4` task, and it *seems* to pass it directly to a utility function that uses it with the `azcopy` command. `AzCopy`, in turn, is supposed to support container to container copies, so you don't seem to be doing anything wrong from that perspective. The only thing I can't really see, because I can't verify the underlying source easily, is if the `Get-VSTSInput` on that parameter is "sanitizing" it somehow???

Comment: Where did/do you find the PS code for that AzureFileCopy@4 task?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks. It's been quite useful to see what happens behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

Azure File Copy task only supports to upload the files from local machine or UNC share to storage account.

You could check the **sourcepath field** definition in task introuduction.

[image]

To Copy Data from Storage Account to Storage Account, you need to use [azcopy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-download) to copy to the file to local machine and use Azure File Copy task to upload the file to another storage account.

```
- script: 'azcopy copy ''https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myBlobDirectory/*'' ''$(build.sourcesdirectory)\myDirectory'''
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  inputs:
    sourcePath: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)\myDirectory'
    azureSubscription: MY-Production-Subscription
    destination: azureBlob
    storage: azcopypipelinetest
    containerName: restored
    additionalArgumentsForBlobCopy: --recursive=true
```